# equivalent versions of axiom of choice

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

> Let $\Omega\neq \emptyset$ and let $\{X_\lambda\}_{\lambda \in \Omega}$ be a collection of sets. Define the Cartesian product of the sets $X_\lambda$ to be $\prod_{\lambda \in \Omega}X_\lambda := \{f : \Omega \to \cup_{\lambda \in \Omega}X_\lambda : f(\lambda ) \in X_\lambda \,\forall \lambda \in \Omega\}.$
> Prove that the following $3$ statements are equivalent:
>
> 1. If $\Omega\neq \emptyset$ and for each $\lambda \in \Omega, X_{\lambda}\neq \emptyset,$ then $\prod_{\lambda \in \Omega}X_\lambda \neq \emptyset$.
> 2. Suppose $\Omega \neq \emptyset$ and that
>
>    - for all $\lambda \in \Omega, X_\lambda \neq \emptyset$, and
>    - $X_\lambda \cap X_\alpha = \emptyset$ if $\lambda \neq \alpha \in \Omega.$
>
>    Then $\prod_{\lambda \in \Omega}X_\lambda \neq \emptyset$.
> 3. Given a nonempty set $X,$ there exists a function $f : \mathcal{P}(X)\backslash \{\emptyset\}\to X$ so that $f(A)\in A$ for all $A \in \mathcal{P}(X)\backslash \{\emptyset\},$ where $\mathcal{P}(X)$ is the power set of $X$.

The above are all versions of the axiom of choice. I'm thinking of showing that $(1)\Leftrightarrow (3)$ and $(1)\Leftrightarrow (2).$ We first show $(1)\Rightarrow (3).$ Suppose $X$ is a nonempty set. Consider $\Omega := \mathcal{P}(X)\backslash \{\emptyset\}\neq \emptyset$ as $X\neq \emptyset.$ Then for each $\lambda \in \Omega,$ define $X_\lambda := \lambda.$ Then $\prod_{\lambda \in \Omega}X_\lambda \neq \emptyset$ by $(1)$. Let $f \in \prod_{\lambda \in \Omega}X_\lambda.$ Then observe that $f : \Omega \to X.$ Also, $f(A)\in A$ for each $A\in \Omega.$ But how can one show $(3)\Rightarrow (1)$? I'm thinking of constructing some sort of power set, but all I have is a nonempty set $\Omega$ and that for each $\lambda \in \Omega, X_{\lambda}\neq \emptyset.$

$(1)\Rightarrow(2)$ is obvious. But $(2)\Rightarrow (1)$ requires me to explicitly construct disjoint $X_\lambda$'s. If $\Omega$ is uncountable, would this result in problems? How could I work around them?

Comment: I don't know why it would matter whether $\Omega$ is uncountable.  How would $\Omega$ being countable make it any easier?

Comment: I can *probably* find you a duplicate for your last question, but it's simpler if I just tell you to replace $X_\lambda$ by $\{\lambda\}\times X_\lambda$.

Comment: @EricWofsey that's just because I was thinking incorrectly. Tbh, the suggestion by asaf karagila makes it clear that $\Omega$ being uncountable doesn't matter.